# How to convert MySQL types to Postgres types in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There is a MySQL DDL as below. I just want to create a similar table in Postgres. 
so How can I convert MySQL DDL to PostgresSQL DDL automatically?

```
 CREATE TABLE `t_abnormal` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `seq_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `reg_no` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `province` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `in_reason` text,
  `in_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `out_reason` text,
  `out_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `department` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  `last_update_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT '-1',
  `ops_flag` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `u_tags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `obj_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `row_update_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `out_department` varchar(100) DEFAULT ''
```

Is there any prepared Python tool or script to achieve this? I'm not sure if `SQLAlchemy` can do this.

Comment: You can't, at least easily. Postgresql does not for example have `ON UPDATE` for datetime, but requires you to create triggers for such.

Comment: Hi . that's can be ignored, actually I just wanna move the data from mysql to postgres.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Create a sort of lookup and map it , this [link](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/python-create-table) should give and idea on how you can begin with then post query if you have any problems with the code